Why did Korach's group get a different form of death?
It’s clear from simple reading of the text that Korach died by getting swallowed up by the ground while the 250 people died by getting consumed by a fire
Question is why didn’t they all die of the same death? I get that Korach was the leader so he may deserve a “unique” death but still why would Hashem cause two unnatural phenomenon when He could just do one and kill them all?

IIRC the text says "וְיָרְדוּ חַיִּים שְׁאֹלָה" meaning they stayed alive in the underworld.

It is exoplained by the HaEmek Dovor written up here. Here is a ChatGPT translation:

But one should understand and contemplate the entire context of the
portion, the nature of the dispute, and the punishment that befell
them. For Korah, Dathan, Abiram, and the two hundred and fifty men did
not all share the same status or intention in their dispute. We see
that only Korah and the two hundred and fifty men took the censers,
not Dathan and Abiram. Additionally, God honored the two hundred and
fifty men, not Korah, Dathan, and Abiram, as will be explained. Thus,
it must be understood that the two hundred and fifty men were truly
great among Israel in every aspect, including their fear of God. Their
desire for the priesthood, which brings closeness and love of God,
burned within them like a fire. This was not for the sake of authority
or imagined honor but to sanctify and achieve this level through
service. They also knew that God's word through Moses was true and did
not question it, God forbid. They only questioned in their hearts
God's will and were willing to sacrifice themselves and die for the
love of God, for love is as strong as death. All this is explained in
the Midrash that Rashi brought, which states: "What did Korah see to
lead him to this foolishness? It is already written that the two
hundred and fifty men sinned with their souls." But Korah, who was
wise, what did he see, etc.? At first glance, it is not clear how this
answers regarding the two hundred and fifty men who sinned with their
souls. [I know there is room to explain according to what is stated in
Sanhedrin (52a) that "with their souls" means in matters of their
souls, that they ate and drank at Korah's house and were thereby
swayed. But it seems that the authors of the Midrash intended
something else.] The meaning of the verse is similar to the
explanation of the verse regarding a Nazir who became impure (Numbers
6:11): "and he shall atone for having sinned regarding the soul." We
explained there that he suffered from abstaining from wine in order to
attain the level of the Holy Spirit and be holy to God, which was not
appropriate for his level. This can be seen from the fact that he
became impure, and the scripture says that one who caused himself
suffering.his soul to achieve the level of the Holy Spirit and to be
holy to God. This was not appropriate for his level. The test for this
is that he became impure, and the scripture says that one who caused
himself suffering to achieve a level beyond his capability is called a
sinner regarding his soul. Similarly, they sought to achieve the level
of love for God through service, even though they knew they would not
be spared and that Moses' words would certainly come true. This is
called "these sinners with their souls," as they sought to sacrifice
their souls only to achieve the level of love and piety, which is not
in accordance with God's will. Therefore, this issue is connected to
the portion of Tzitzit, where the pious ones were warned with a thread
of blue, so that in all their piety, they would not stray from God's
commandments, as we explained in the warning "and you shall not
follow..." The two hundred and fifty men rebelled against this and
thus received their punishment. It was impossible for them to take
censers or similar items and offer them in the Tabernacle because the
Levites guarded against unauthorized persons approaching. Therefore,
they had to create a dispute against Moses and Aaron and breach the
boundaries. This was the way of the two hundred and fifty men, and
because they intended for the sake of Heaven, they were punished by
burning with fire that came out from the Holy of Holies, which also
involved an element of honor, as will be explained. Not so with Dathan
and Abiram. They were far from this lofty desire, being naturally
argumentative and enemies of Moses even back in Egypt, as stated in
Nedarim 64b. All the more so now, when it was decreed that they would
die in the desert and not enter the land flowing with milk and honey.
Therefore, they were punished by being swallowed up by the earth like
an animal. However, Korah was truly a great man and fit for the desire
of the two hundred and fifty men. It appeared to people that he too
was seeking this, but in truth, his inner self was not so, and
jealousy for power consumed him. Therefore, he acted like the two
hundred and fifty men and was punished like Dathan and Abiram.


HaEmek HaDavar is translated properly on Sefaria AFAIK
